# replace statement query in CI

Tags: php, mysql, replace, codeigniter-3

i have this table

```
id | part_number | desc | date       |
1  | 3yrt3470    | aa   | 2017-02-20 |
2  | 3utitj40    | bb   | 2017-02-12 |
```

pk=id

i want to create query insert into table but if part_number exist it will updated. anyone can help me?
i tried this

```
function replace($part_number)
{
    $this->db->replace('tbl_master_data');
    $this->db->set('description',$description);
    $this->db->set('rrp',$rrp);
    $this->db->set('discount_code',$discount_code);
    $this->db->set('product_group',$product_group);
    $this->db->set('value_discount',$value_discount);
    $this->db->set('stk',$stk);
    $this->db->where('part_number',$part_number);
}
```

error messages show you must use the 'set' method...

Comment: The reason you are getting that error is that you are calling the replace method before you perform the sets and where methods. So put the replace as the very last statement in your function... Then you should get a bunch of errors saying your variables ( except for $part_number) are not defined.

Comment: It's always worth reading the user guide... This doesn't answer your insert/update question but you should be aware of this... https://www.codeigniter.com//user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=replace#inserting-data

Comment: ok, now i want to find part_number and then if part_number exist it will replace, can tell me how query it's work?